# How to do hibernate spatial delete?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, cascade, cascading-deletes, hibernate-spatial

I want to delete my database datas.

This is AJAX code taken from value from the TextBox :

```
 function deleteVector()
{
    var value = $('#hs').val();
    console.log(value);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/deleteGeoJson",
        data: {id: value},
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function (data) {
            var parser = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
            var feature = parser.read(data.data);
        }
    });
}
```

this is my button code :

Delete

and this is my controller ( get method )

```
 SavegeojsonManager add = new SavegeojsonManager();

 @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteGeoJson", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public GeoJSON deleteGeoJson( final HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("id") final int vectorId) {
    return add.delete(vectorId);
}
```

this is SavegeojsonManager class codee :

```
 public GeoJSON delete(int id) {

    GeoJSON geoJson = new GeoJSON();
    try{
        EntityManager em = HibernateSpatialJPA.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        //How can I continue ?
       //If there's one thing if it is connected to the data you delete it
      //so cascade ??

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return geoJson;
}
```

}

and this is GeoJSON Class :

```
private int id;
 public int getId() { return id; }
public void setId(int id) {  this.id = id; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all when you are deleting entity you cant return instance of that deleted entity in you example.

You could do in this way:
In you your view for example in `jsp` you can show that message that has been sent via `Controller`. Propably in `ajax` request from `success` part of it.

**Controller code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteGeoJson", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String deleteGeoJson( final HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("id") final int vectorId) {
    String message = null;
    boolean deleted = add.delete(vectorId);
    if(deleted){
        message = "Geo object has been deleted with id: "+vectorId;
    } else {
        message = "There was some problem with deleting GeoObject"
    }
    return message;
}
```

**Your dao code:**
This can be done in many ways:

```
 public boolean delete(int id) {
 boolean deleted = false;
 try{
    EntityManager em = HibernateSpatialJPA.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Query query = em.createQuery("delete SavegeojsonEntity s where s.id = :id");
    query.setParameter("id", id);

    int result = query.executeUpdate();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    if(result > 0){
        deleted = true;
    }

 } catch (Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
 }
return deleted;
}
```

Comment: Updated in dao code. Missing `em.getTransaction().commit()`

Comment: Thanks ! @PawelGłowacz